# Measuring Code Coverage for a UWP App

Tags: c#, uwp, code-coverage

For a standard CSharp/UWP App, is there a good way to measure Unitest code coverage? It looks like Visual Studio tools do not apply for UWP. My end goal is to get an objective measurement for how thorough our testing is, and to watch for regressions on coverage.

Comment: AFAIK, Visual Studio currently don’t support code coverage for UWP App. You can refer the [similar question in MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ff866c7b-f560-4e04-ab2e-597cd5c52cf7/how-to-check-code-coverage-for-universal-windows-packageuwp-apps?forum=vsunittest).

Answer (score 1):

I have gotten code coverage to work for the following configuration, using VS2015:

- Create a Portable Class Library (PCL) project.
- In Project Properties, re-target the project to .NETStandard1.4 (see [the official compatibility matrix](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions.md) for why to choose v1.4).
- Reference the PCL project from your UWP app.
- For the test project, use xUnit and a .NET Core class library, setting it up as described in the [xUnit docs](http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dotnet-core).

If you can minimize the amount of code in your UWP app project (e.g., by using the MVVM pattern), then most of your tests will be against the PCL. Since code coverage works against a .NET Standard library set up as shown, your numbers will be fairly accurate even if you can't measure coverage against the UWP app project itself.

(Of course, this is more practical for new apps than existing apps, since it requires a particular design).